# Including other libraries / files / plugins with nodejs and NPM

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, npm

I'm using OSX 10.5 and playing around with Nodejs. I've managed to install npm and used it to install a couple of plugins. Well at least the installation says it has worked fine but when I try and load them in I get an error

```
$npm install htmlparser
```

Installs ok, then I create a file called test with

```
var htmlparser = require("node-htmlparser");
```

and run

```
$node test.js
```

I get

> ```
> var htmlparser = require("node-htmlparser");
> node.js:275
>         throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
> ```

I have this in my `.bash_profile` file:

```
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"
```

If I clone the GIT repos at [this page](http://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) and move the file `lib/node-htmlparser.js` to `~/.node_libraries` then it works fine.

What is the point of using npm to install anything if I have to move the lib file like this? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

`var htmlparser = require('htmlparser')` should work fine, since they knock the 'node' off the name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the exact name that you use to install the module via NPM.

If you do
`npm install htmlparser`

Then your syntax for using the module should be
    `var htmlparser = require("htmlparser");`

If that doesn't work, I'd check your npm and/or node install, but with all the details you listed above, that should work fine.